# Lambda expression for LineListener

Tags: java, lambda

),

These days I replaced anonymous listener with lambda expressions. For actionlisteners this works fine:

```
name_button.addActionListener(e->{
            gui.game_menu(Saving_Handler.new_game(filenumber, name_field.getText()));
            namer.dispose();
        });
```

But with the linelistener i have some difficulties. This is the expression i want to transform:

```
void sound_mission_start()
{
    if (sound) {
        try {
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("rsc/mission_start.wav")));
            clip.start();
            clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
                public void update(LineEvent myLineEvent) {
                    if (myLineEvent.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
                        clip.close();
                    }
                }
            });
        } 
        catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}
```

How I twist and turn, I'm not able to bring the LineEvent and the if() together.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: myLineEvent becomes not declareded. Declareding it outside seems not possible cause I the constructor needs the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to define a lambda expression that takes in a LineEvent and has no return. Since the if statement makes it more than a single statement in the body of the lambda you need to have brackets.

```
            clip.addLineListener( myLineEvent -> {
                if (myLineEvent.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
                    clip.close();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Damn, I think now i got it, ty :)